# Convert random to int visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, winforms, random, visual-studio-2015

why is this not working?
It is in visual studo 2015, windows forms application C#

```
namespace guessing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int rndm = rnd.Next(1, 13);
```

there is an error under rnd, which says:

> "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Form1.rnd' "

Comment: Probably you want to write those lines in a method, like a `Main` maybe?

Answer (score 6):

In C#, statements cannot occur immediately under a class declaration. They need to be part of a function or method.

```
namespace guessing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        void MethodX()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int rndm = rnd.Next(1, 13);
            /* to be continued... */ 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note this is very unreliable code; if `MethodX` were called in a loop it could use the same `Random` seed and bias the result of `Next`. `rnd` should probably be a class variable initialized in the constructor.

Comment: of course. just to make the code compile to get the OP started. no assumptions of his functional intentions made.

Comment: @dlatikay : This would be answer-worthy if you return the `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, as Soner Gönül said, you have to add this code to a Method in your Form. Because you probably created the Form with the Designer, just go to the Events and create a method `created` (or similar). Then put your code into the body of the created method.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
namespace guessing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int rndm = new Random().Next(1, 13);
```

**Edit**

In response to TomTom:

There are many ways to approach this. If you need to keep an instance of `Random` available at all times, define it on the class level as you already have.

```
namespace guessing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int rndm = new Random().Next(1, 13);

        // Or make it static.
        static Random rand = new Random();
        int rndm = Form1.rand.Next(1, 13);

        // Or a method
        private int GetRandomInteger()
        {
            return new Random().Next(1, 13);
            // or call your class level instance of Random
        }
```

Comment: I will -1 that because it has a different semantics. In concrete you have no way to get another random number from the same Random instance.

Comment: @TomTom : @Tal was defining the `int` variable on the class level. I am assuming that Tal wants a random number. You are assuming that Tal wants to have hundreds of random numbers.

Comment: Actually no. I assume Tal read the rules here and came up with a VERY simple example to demonstrate a problem. I really assume he does not want a single random number and just used this as an example.

Comment: @TomTom : This would be the same as defining a `Random` object inside of a method.